# code is to generate a probability, choose it, then pull it from a mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $shadeprobability = new ProbabilityRandom;  
 $shadeprobability->add($mothershade,10);  
 $shadeprobability->add($fathershade,10);  
 $shadeprobability->add("1000",100);  
 $shadeprobability->add("1001",25);  
 $shadeprobability->add("1002",15);  
 $shadeprobability->add("1003",25);  
 $shadeprobability->add("1004",15);  
 $shadeprobability->add("1005",15);  
 $shadeprobability->add("1006",25);  
 $shadeprobability->add("1007",15);  
 $shade = $shadeprobability->get();  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `shade` LIMIT 0, 30 ";  
 $arrayshade = $shade;
```

I'm not sure how to get the  $shade = $shadeprobability ->get(); to goto the database and find a match and then store that in $arrayshade